# sql server sharding (sharing common data like masters)

Tags: sql-server, sharding

I was going through the sharding pattern:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589797.aspx

Can someone help me to understand how can we shard a database where we are sharing masters and few other common tables across all shards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from an other database table using following syntax

```
select * from TestDB.dbo.tbl
```

TestDB is an other database than the current db.
dbo is schema name
tbl is the target database name.

This enables reading data from other databases on the same SQL Server instance